# unable to remove malware from wp website

Tags: plugins, virus

I recently submitted my website to adwords and it was rejected due to malacious software or link. The link detected in www.ws30.coinhive.com .

I have scanned my wordpress website using plugins such as wordfence, sucuri etc. but none seem to delete the malacious link. I am a newbie and i used a page builder to make this website, so i have no coding knowledge.

Can you please suggest step-wise, where can i find this link and remove it? any youtube video? i need help urgently.

Comment: there is only one step :( hire someone that specializes in that. Once infected the only solution is to get back to a known good backup, but in your case you do not even know what would be such a good backup.

Comment: Yes, as @MarkKaplun has suggested, it sounds like you'll need to hire a specialist developer to scan your site manually in order to find the malicious code.

Answer (score 1):

Over the years, I have developed a process/procedure to recover a hacked site. While backups are good, it's not always clear that a backup is 'clean' and not hacked.

My process includes reinstalling all code (WP, plugins, themes) manually (themes/plugins via FTP from known good source, WP via the 'update again' on the Update page), changing all credentials (hosting, email, users, database), and more; and manual inspection of files.

It can be time consuming, and I believe is much more thorough than automated scanning tools or services.

My process is here: http://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ .

Good luck.